# How to attach a div to the bottom of the other so that the content is scrollable

Tags: html, css

Ok so basically I have:

```
<div style="overflow-x:scroll">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="text"></div>
        <div class="seperator"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to position the bottom div (its basically a sort of horizontal line) on the bottom of the content div

I've tried the `position: absolute` embedding a `position: relative` div tag, but because the top div is scrollable the seperators remain fixed when I scroll

How would I go abouts getting this done (I have to use the seperator in the `class=content` div so it doesnt ruin the background I have set for it

Edit: Ok so my seperator has some shadows and stuff so I need it to overlay with the content, so I need some kind of absolute positioning, but not to the page, to the 'top div'

Is there a way to relatively position it so it'll always be at the bottom of the parent div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#top-div { position:relative; /* fixed height or width */ }
#bot-div { position:absolute; bottom:0 }
```

Comment: I created this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/7PS26/

But the seperator I have doesnt show up (it has a bit of transparency to it so I need it to overlap the text - the equivalent of what would be a picture or other content)

Comment: Is it something like this that you want? http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/7PS26/1/

Comment: @Akshat Your markup seems rather crazy in that fiddle. Are you sure that you got that right?

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
.sep {
 border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5)   
 position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}​
```

To this:

```
.sep {
 border-bottom: 4px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}​
```

If I am not understanding your question please feel free to correct me.